# Conversion error with simple SQL UPDATE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an application that is using SQL Server 2016 for backend storage. I have the following statement I'm trying to run:

```
UPDATE dbo.AspNetUsers
SET [IsActive] = 1
WHERE [Id] = '1b08b7a9-2978-4116-8a9c-e86bc9ae8bbf'
```

- `[IsActive]` is a `BIT` column
- `[Id]` is a `NVARCHAR(128)` column

When executing, I get the following error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tUserActiveChange, Line 21 [Batch Start Line 4]
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1b08b7a9-2978-4116-8a9c-e86bc9ae8bbf' to data type int.

Seems like a pretty straightforward update statement. I even tried the same type of statement on another database on the same server where the updated column is a `BIT` and using a `VARCHAR` column for the `WHERE` condition and it worked just fine.

What the heck?

Comment: Your Id field (in the table)is NOT NvarChar(128). It is in fact defined as Int. You must have another column in the table defined as GUID

Comment: Are you sure `id` type is not `int`? please run `sp_help AspNetUsers` and confirm.

Comment: I double checked, and [Id] is VARCHAR(128)

Comment: Can you add dbo.AspNetUsers table schema?

Comment: And the code of tUserActiveChange procedure.

Comment: You could try casting ID as VARCHAR(128) in the where clause, but if it is reading it as an INT then I imagine that will need to be solved regardless.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I realized I had a trigger I created a while back that is causing the error (tUserActiveChange). The trigger updates another table when IsActive changes.  It was, in fact, trying to assign a VARCHAR variable to an int field.
I fixed that and now the UPDATE statement is working fine. Thank you all for taking the time to look into this. I feel silly now haha.